# Quasi-isometric Riemannian Metrics on Manifold

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry, compactness, smooth-manifolds, tangent-spaces

Two Riemannian Metrics $g$ and $h$ on a Manifold $M$ are **Quasi-isometric** if there exist positive constants $A$ and $B$ such that $$A\|u\|_g\leq\|u\|_h\leq B\|u\|_g$$ for any $u \in T(N)$. where $\|\cdot\|_g$ and $\|\cdot\|_h$ are the norms determined by $g$ and $h$, respectively.

The questiones are

1. Is it possible that a complete riemannian metric is quasi-isometric to incomplete one?
2. Is it true that if the manifold is compact then any two Riemannian metrics on it are quasi-isometric?

Comment: For 2., see my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3721163/if-m-is-a-compact-riemannian-manifold-and-g-and-tildeg-are-metrics-on/3721194#3721194)