# constant in equivalent metrics

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I know in a compact Riemannian manifold, [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3721163/if-m-is-a-compact-riemannian-manifold-and-g-and-tildeg-are-metrics-on) on equivalence of metrics hold. As a consequence, we can take an arbitrary compact Riemannian $N$-manifold $(M,g)$ with its covering by the charts $(U_k,\phi_k)$ for $k=1,2,\dots,m$ and we have the following relation $$\frac1Q|\phi_k^{-1}(x)-\phi_k^{-1}(y)|\leq d_g(x,y)\leq Q|\phi_k^{-1}(x)-\phi_k^{-1}(y)|$$ for all $x,y\in M$ and some $Q>1$. As usual, $d_g$ is the geodesic distance.

I want to know if there is a way to explicitly calculate this constant $Q$. If not, is it possible to say upto what extent this constant $Q$ could depend on the manifold $(M,g)$? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to be a bit careful, there need not exist a chart in your covering that contains both $x$ and $y$.